# System.Data.OleDb Missing - What to use instead

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

With my Web API built in VS Code, I have an adapter class that is specific to Microsoft Access, however, using System.Data.OleDb isn't working because I'm missing a reference which I can't add. What alternative to OleDb will give me the same access to MS Access?

Comment: And just why can you not add a reference?

Comment: Because I've tried installing System.Data.OleDb through the NuGet package manager and it doesn't exist.

Comment: The best way to start is to see what kind of Adapter do you have on the machine, you can refer the steps in this blog http://lifeastechie.blogspot.com/2016/10/how-to-check-database-connection.html.  Also, what version of .NET framework are you on? You don't get these adapter thru Nuget Packages.

Answer (score 0):

You still need the Access Database Engine.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255